# Weird blue outline/border search button iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, bootstrap-4, border

I've got a weird blue border that only seems to appear on iOS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXjvG.jpg)

I think I've tried every :focus :active variation possible and I just can't find it and I don't even can reproduce te border in any inspect on any browser. So I'm a bit lost.

This is the code

```html
<li class="menu--list__items zoeken nav-item">
            <a class="menu--list__items--link nav-link" href="#" id="zoekenDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Zoeken
                <i class="material-icons">
                    search
                </i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu animate slideIn zoeken--dropdown" aria-labelledby="zoekenDropdown">
                <input class="form-control dropdown-item" id="zoeken-term" type="search" name="q"  placeholder="Waar bent u naar op zoek?" autocomplete="off" aria-label="Search">
                <button type="submit" class="zoeken--dropdown--btn">
                    <i class="material-icons">
                        search
                    </i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be the right or perfect answer, but have you tried to use `!important`?

In combination with `:focus` or `:active` it should work.
If it is only on IOS this could probably help you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions

Comment: Thnx that put me in the right direction by adding this it was solved 
                    &:focus {
                        outline: 0 !important;
                        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
                        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
                        -webkit-user-select: none;
                        -khtml-user-select: none;
                        -moz-user-select: none;
                        -ms-user-select: none;
                        user-select: none; 
                    }

Answer (score 3):

```
This worked for me in the end

            &:focus {
                    outline: 0 !important;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
                    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
                    -webkit-user-select: none;
                    -khtml-user-select: none;
                    -moz-user-select: none;
                    -ms-user-select: none;
                    user-select: none; 
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `outline: none;` and ***:focus*** ***:active*** won't work in this condition.

**TYR `outline: none;`**

Check out this...

```css
.btn{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button class="btn">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```